# Azure Databricks Delta live table

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

1. Azure Databricks Delta live table tab is missing from my Databricks notebooks. Why?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question doesn't require a code.

Answer (score 0):

Delta Live Table access control is available only in the [Premium plan or above](https://www.databricks.com/product/aws-pricing?_ga=2.216605782.1321552439.1667465317-1168367297.1657265233).

Enabling access control for Delta Live Tables allows pipeline owners to control pipeline access, including permissions to view pipeline details, start and stop pipeline updates, and manage pipeline settings.

This article describes individual consent and how to configure pipeline [access control](https://docs.databricks.com/security/access-control/dlt-acl.html).